# Adding Multiple Filters to one column in Kendo Grid with Angular 5

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, filtering, angular5

I need to add **multiple filtering for one column** in Kendo Grid with Angular 5. 
When I click on a column, the following should appear and I should be able to filter from the selected filters.

[This is an example image of the filtering I need.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuDY2.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please get familiar with [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Provide us code and what have you tried.